# Cannot call a function in a C program

Tags: arrays, c, loops

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100

void max_min(int arr[MAX_SIZE]) {
  int i, j;
//maximum loop below
  int max;
  max = arr[0];
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(arr[i]); ++i) {
    if ((arr[i]) > max) {
      arr[i] = max;
    }
    if ((arr[i]) < max) {
      break;
    }
  }
  printf("Largest = %d", max);
//minimum loop below
  int min;
  min = arr[0];
  for (j = 0; j < sizeof(arr[j]); ++i) {
    if ((arr[j]) < min) {
      arr[j] = min;
    }
    if ((arr[j]) > min) {
      break;
    }
  }

int main(void) {
  int arr[MAX_SIZE];
  printf("Enter 10 elements for array > ");
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
  }
  printf("Your array is: \n");
  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    printf("%d", arr[i]);
    printf(" ");
  }
  max_min(arr[MAX_SIZE]);
  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to write a min, max loop as I typed above. The problem is when I don't call function and enter 10 number inputs, the array print loop works fine and it takes an array. When I call array by `max_min(arr[MAX_SIZE]);` the array print loop stops working and the program doesn't go further. Appreciate any help.

Comment: By the way, `sizeof(arr[i]) == sizeof(int)`.  If you need your function to know how many elements are valid in the array, then you must pass that number as an additional parameter to the function.

Comment: If you indent your code you'll find that the `max_min` function is lacking the end `}`. Also, `max_min(arr[MAX_SIZE]);` is only sending in _one_ `int` to the function (and it's out of bounds) - also `sizeof(arr[i]);` is not going to work. Neither will `sizeof(arr);` since arrays decay into pointers to the first element when passed as arguments to functions. You are also using the wrong variable in `for (j = 0; j < sizeof(arr[j]); ++i){`

Comment: Thanks a lot for comment Ted, it also worked

Comment: @09-15-00 Great! I made a proper answer out of it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call your function with `max_min(arr)`, not `max_min(arr[MAX_SIZE])`.

`arr[MAX_SIZE]` is trying to access the element at index 100 in your array, but valid indexes only range from 0 to 99.

Passing `arr` will pass the array pointer instead, which is what the function is expecting.

Comment: Yeah this worked and called function thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

If you indent your code you'll find that the `max_min` function is lacking the end `}`. Also, `max_min(arr[MAX_SIZE]);` is only sending in *one* `int` to the function (and it's out of bounds) - also `sizeof(arr[i]);` is not going to work and neither will `sizeof(arr);` since arrays decay into pointers to the first element when passed as arguments to functions. You need to send in the number of elements in the array as an argument to the function.

You assign `arr[i] = max;` and `arr[i] = min;` in your loops when it should be `max = arr[i];` and `min = arr[i];`.

You are also using the wrong variable in `for (j = 0; j < sizeof(arr[j]); ++i)` (note the `++i` which should be `++j`).

Example fix:

```
#include <stddef.h>

void max_min(int arr[], size_t count) {
    int min = arr[0];
    int max = arr[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < count; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] > max) max = arr[i];
        else if (arr[i] < min) min = arr[i];
    }
    printf("Smallest = %d\nLargest = %d\n", min, max);
}
```

And call it with:

```
max_min(arr, 10); // where 10 is the number of values the user has entered
```

Comment: Size_t's in front of for loops at maximum, minimum loops also helped getting unstuck at some random point. Thanks again, Ted! I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: @09-15-00 Glad it helped. You're welcome!